# get google map zoom level when using fitBounds

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I want to get google map current zoom level, it gives me undefined error, I think because I don't use explicit zoom level in my map creation options, rather I use map.fitBounds, how can I get google map zoom level when I'm using map.fitBounds?

this is my code summary:

```
var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.panToBounds(bounds);
```

now, when I want to use map.getZoom(), I get undefined, it seems that getZoom only returns explicitly set zoom levels

Comment: Can we see what code you're using so far?

Comment: Show us where in your code you're using getZoom.  Possibly it's `map` which is undefined because you're trying to access it outwith the function it was created in

Comment: I use map.getZoom() after map.panToBounds(bounds), my map is defined here

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API v3 is event based.  When the new zoom level is available to be queried, the zoom_changed event will fire.

To get the new zoom, do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
  alert("the zoom level is now "+map.getZoom());
});
```

Note that this will fire every time the zoom is changed.

Comment: thanks, but it does nothing, please look at this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/KwayW/26/

Comment: thanks, I use fitBounds, but as you can see, my zoom level is not really FIT, I can still make another zoom-in and my markers will be still visible, is it a google map bug? how can I fix it?

Comment: all fitBounds does is guarantee that the complete bounds will be visible on the map.  It looks like it is leaving space along the left edge for the controls.